# Getting the number of tabs in a TabBar

Tags: gwt

How can I find the number of tabs in a TabBar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GetTabCount](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabBar.html)() should return this for you.